# how to sort field with char and decimal value

Tags: jpql

i am stuck with the scenario where i have to sort 
'a-2.3'
'a-1.1' and 
'a-1.02'. 
how do we do this using jpql in spring data jpa or using sql query. I would appreciate your personal experience and idea.

the sorting expected in ascending order based on the numerical value after a-  .

Answer (score 0):

This will depend on the database you're using, but e.g. in Oracle, you could call `TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(col, 3))` with SQL:

```sql
WITH t (col) AS (
  SELECT 'a-2.3'  FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'a-1.1'  FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'a-1.02' FROM dual
)
SELECT col
FROM t 
ORDER BY to_number(substr(col, 3))
```

This yields:

```
a-1.02
a-1.1
a-2.3
```

Of course, you'll have to adapt the parsing in case your prefix isn't always exactly `a-`, but something dynamic.

In JPQL, this could be feasible: `CAST(SUBSTRING(col, 3, LENGTH(col) - 2) AS NUMBER)`

Comment: Thank you Eder for your sharing. It gave me idea on using cast and substring concept.